# Image::Imlib2->load("filename") says file doesn't exists even though it does

Tags: perl

```
use Image::Imlib2;
my $a = Image::Imlib2->load("/foo/file");
```

gives me the following error:

```
Runtime error: Image::Imlib2 load error: File does not exist at (eval 469) line 6.
```

Note that /foo/file is a CIFS mounted directory and this only happens for files on CIFS mounted directories.  An additional complication is that this happens on Debian Squeeze but not on Debian Lenny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to mount the CIFS directory using the 'noserverino' option.

Image::Imlib2 is a Perl wrapper around the Imlib2 C library.  The problem is CIFS servers can return inode integer values > 31^2. This makes programs not compiled with LFS (Large File Support), to throw a glibc EOVERFLOW error. Either compile the program with LFS support (i.e. with -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64) or use the "noserverino" mount option. But you may not be able to detect hardlinks properly.

http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs